# How to use CSS Variables only when they exist?

Tags: html, css, css-variables

I have some CSS where I want a default color and then override it with a variable. When the CSS Variable doesn't exist, I want to use the fallback color.

```
:root {
    /*--tintColor: red;*/
}

.text {
    color: blue;
    color: var(--tintColor);
}
```

When the variable isn't set like if its commented out the color becomes black. I want it in this case that the color falls back to the blue when the variable isn't defined. Is this possible?

Comment: [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var) - `var(--tintColor, blue)`

Comment: Amazing! ^ never actually check the docs and just been using SASS but this is lovely

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can specify the [**`fallback`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var#Values) property like `var(--tintColor, blue)` - see demo below:

```css
.text {
    color: var(--tintColor, blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="text">some text here</div>
<div class="text" style="--tintColor: red">some text here</div>
```

Comment: this line `color: blue;` is redunant in 2k20 :3

Comment: @vovchisko Good point, but it may be useful to keep it for some HTML to PDF conversion tools that aren't always up to date with the latest CSS modules. Typically, [it seems that wkhtmltopdf was handling it and no longer now, probably by error](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/4827).

Comment: What if the first variable is removed dynamically? In that case it doesn't seem to fall back the second variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use another variable as the fallback:

```
:root {
   /* --color1: #999; */
   --color2: #333;
}

.class {
  color: var(--color1, var(--color2));
}
```